# Amazon S3 response in JSON?

Tags: json, amazon-s3

According to the doc http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html the S3 service seems to respond in XML.

Is there a way to get it in JSON format instead?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

No.

Also the response is not always valid XML! This is a known bug in S3. In S3 you can use *any* UTF-8 string as a key for an object, including ones with XML invalid characters (<, > etc are fine) but some weird control characters are NOT.

So if somehow you get a file up on S3 with a weird enough string as a key, asking for a listing of that will return invalid XML!

So perhaps they could fix this bug by making some sort of JSON return as an option, but don't look for it soon. The XML bug has been known for years. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=10869
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=82485

Another sore point is that its impossible (at least when I tried a year ago) to get the XML response gzipped. So you waste lots of bandwidth transmitting very fluffy XML.

It's time for S3 to support a new returned data format that is compressed and robust.

Comment: Haven't fixed for years? No way I'm going to use S3.

Comment: The devil you know is better than the one you don't. S3 has a trillion objects stored, so its got proven reliability. Every single bit of software every written has bugs.

Comment: Rekindling this 10 years later.   Yes, the aws cli is great and can emit JSON but the `curl` API should def honor `Accept:  application/json` in the header.